# cancel recurring tasks when I cancel a case

Tags: apex, trigger

How do I cancel the recurring tasks when I cancel a case? Can this be done using trigger? I want to cancel all the tasks that are present under this case. It showing an error msg that recurring task status field cant be updated.

```
public static void onAfterUpdate(List<Case> newCases){
    set<id> caseIdSet = new set<id>();
    list<task> toUpdateTaskLst = new list<task> ();
    for(case c : newcases)
    {
        caseIdSet.add(c.id);   
        system.debug('caseIdSet  '+caseIdSet);
    }
    for(case c: [select Id , (select id, whatid, status from tasks) from Case where id in :caseIdSet and status in ('Closed','Cancelled','Deleted') ] )
    {
        if(!c.tasks.isEmpty() && c.tasks != null )
        {
            for(task t: c.tasks)
            {
                system.debug('t.status'+t.status);
               // t.status = 'Completed';
                  t.RecurrenceEndDateOnly = Date.today();
                toUpdateTaskLst.add(t);
            }
        }
    }
    update toUpdateTaskLst;

}
```

Comment: Whenever you get an error, please include its message *verbatim*. Without that, this question is off topic as it's just a guessing game what actually went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IsRecurrence` field is ReadOnly except on create, so your trigger needs to change the `RecurrenceEndDateOnly` field's value to `today()`. You could even use `today().addDays(- 1)`, provided it's not less than the `RecurrenceStartDateOnly` since `today()` won't end until midnight. Once you do that, all future Tasks will be deleted and completed tasks will still be preserved.

From the section below "Tasks" in the [Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_task.htm), here's an excerpt on the discussion related to Recurring Tasks:

> **Recurring Tasks**
>
> - Recurring tasks are available in API version 16.0 and later.
> - After a task is created, it can’t be changed from recurring to nonrecurring or vice versa.
> - When you delete a recurring task series through the API, all open and closed task occurrences in the series are removed. However, when you delete a recurring task series through the user interface, only open tasks occurrences (IsClosed is false) in the series are removed.
> - If IsRecurrence is true, then RecurrenceStartDateOnly, RecurrenceEndDateOnly, RecurrenceType, and any properties associated with the given recurrence type (see the following table) must be populated.
> - When you change the RecurrenceStartDateOnly field or the recurrence pattern, all open tasks occurrences in the series are deleted and new open task occurrences are created based on the new recurrence pattern. The recurrence pattern is determined by the following fields: RecurrenceType, RecurrenceTimeZoneSidKey, RecurrenceInterval, RecurrenceDayOfWeekMask, RecurrenceDayOfMonth, RecurrenceInstance, and RecurrenceMonthOfYear.
> - When you change the value of RecurrenceEndDateOnly to an earlier date (for example, from January 20th to January 10th), all open task occurrences in the series with the ActivityDate value greater than the new end date value are deleted. Other open and closed task occurrences in the series are not affected.
> - When you change the value of RecurrenceEndDateOnly to a later date (for example, from January 10th to January 20th), new task occurrences are created up to the new end date. Existing open and closed tasks in the series are not affected.

Comment: Hi I have changed my code , but now it shows the error that Apex task trigger cannot handle batch operations . How do I resolve it

Comment: Your question has been put on hold. Please edit your question with exact error message you are now receiving to have it reopened. I strongly suspect the problem you are having is because of the query for loop in your code containing the subquery. I would rewrite this as a single query that returns a map, then use the map results to iterate on Task to create your list of Tasks to update.